# chrome NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID, datetime correct

Tags: google-chrome

I have been having this issue since long and i tried a lot of things to resolve this issue.

So every page that i open on google chrome i get NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID. Even if i open google.com

I tried reinstalling chrome,even installed canary but in vain.

My system datetime is correct.

I can access any page through firefox however. Have anyone got this issue earlier. I know that its maybe not the best place to post this question, but i tried looking for answers many places and could still not resolve this issue. Any help is most welcome. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Try changing the date and time on your computer's bios.

Comment: Consider using arguments as to why this might solve the problem. One could say "try squeezing a lemon on your knee" and it wouldn't be so different from your answer.